# How to improve the speed of directory creation

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I am wanting to create around 1000 folders onto a 16GB FAT32 USB but it takes around 1-2 minutes. That seems a little absurd for just directories. Are there any ways to speed this up?

I would look up other things to try but I have found nothing. Changing from FAT32 to NTFS improves speed drastically but unfortunately I cannot use that. Currently I am testing out of powershell running a very basic for loop script to create directories.

```
for ($i=1;$i -le 1000;$i++){MD "D:\$i"}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are already in the directory where you want to create the folders, you can simply run the following because the `-Path` parameter accepts an array.

```
new-item -itemtype directory -path (1..1000)
```

If significant time is wasted displaying output to the console, you can use `$null` to suppress that.

```
$null = new-item -itemtype directory -path (1..1000)
```

Comment: That still takes a significant amount of time on my drive which still is not making sense to me